# IIS 403 - Forbidden, when use web url

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having this strange problem.
I have a web application installed on IIS7
I can access the website without any issues when I use servers local ip address however when I point to it using
https://www.xyz.com
I get 403-Forbidden access denied error

Can some one pls help?

Thanks

Comment: What OS? Does ping www.xyz.com resolves to your webserver? Are you trying to access it from the same server?

Answer (score 2):

The reason of this issue may because that your default page is incorrect. You have to make sure the default page include the page you want.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. When I used the IP address, I was using it like

```
0.0.1/Index.aspx
```

and I had missed setting up the default document on the web server. As soon as I set the default document, it worked.